# :selected returns false for an option of a select element which has multiple attribute set on runtime

Tags: jquery, select, multiple-select

Consider the following situation,

I have a select element

```
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option selected="selected">b</option>
    <option selected="selected">c</option>
</select>
```

Then using jquery I set the multiple attribute

```
$( 'select' ).attr( 'multiple', true );
```

Why does the following code returns false?

```
$( 'select' ).children( 'option' ).eq( 1 ).is( ':selected' )
```

While this returns true,

```
$( 'select' ).children( 'option' ).eq( 2 ).is( ':selected' )
```

But if the select element's multiple attribute was set manually on the HTML code, both of them returns true. (tried on webkit, firefox and IE)

Is it a mistake on my side, or is this the expected behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the select is rendered without multiple attribute set, only the last selected option is actually selected. You would need to set the selected options after you allow multiple values.

Both your queries return what you expect. The thing you miss is that your **b** option is actually not selected. Check what is rendered in browser.

EDIT: This line fixes the behaviour, add it after your multiple selection activation:

```
$('select').html($('select').html());
```

Comment: On chrome dev tools, I see both options has the selected attribute, but when querying it with :selected through jquery, it doesn't return the expected result. If I inspect the element using pure javascript, they also has the selected attribute. Any ideas?

Comment: You are right, but still, even Chrome renders only **c** selected. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgvrF/2). I would say what you want is quite unusual to expect it to work ;) At least the problem is not in jQuery..

Comment: Yeah I see, so this is an impossible thing to do without specifying the multiple attribute manually :( Thanks for your answer..

Comment: Actually there is a way... Updating my answer.

Comment: Great, I'll go with this. Thanks a lot :)